# I can not set THM files to asp:image control

Tags: asp.net, image, thumbnails, aspxgridview, imageurl

Why doesn't the image show up when the file extension is THM.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:image id="ThumbImg" runat="server"  imageurl='<%# GeThumb(Container.DataItem) %>' Width ="60px" Height = "60px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

The above lines are within asp:gridview in ASPX page.

GetThumb returns url as below.

http://www.xyz.com/images/mythumbnailimage.THM

The image doesn't show on the grid and I don't get to see the typical RED Colored x mark but it is different. In any case the image doesn't show in the grid. The image file exists on the server but will render when I change extension to JPG or TIF.

So my question is what's wrong with THM files. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the image extensions (THM in my case) needs to be added in the server. Added and it started working.